# Marksheet program: addition in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to make a marksheet in php, mysql using CodeIgnitor. I have used XAMPP and created a database.to store each record.The data is being retrieved from the database, The new record inserted edited successfully

But the problem is in retrieving the sum. It is not giving me the sum answer means total marks. I am pasting the code here, please help me or correct me If I am wrong, as I am new to CodeIgnitor.

I have also tried the function `array_sum()`, But it also not giving me any answer. And It is not giving me any error about the code or any query. Either query about sum in marksheet is wrong or the answer can't be fetched by view.

Model/marksheet.php file

```
function tm() {
  $data = array(
              'math' => $_POST['math'],
              'eng' => $_POST['eng'],
              'bio' => $_POST['bio'],
              'total_marks' => $_POST['total_marks']);
              $this->db->insert('marks', $data);

  // $mark = array_sum($data);

  $mark= $_POST['math'] + $_POST['eng'] + $_POST['bio'];
  return $mark;
}
```

**Controller/welcome.php file**

```
public function sum() {
   $data['page_title'] = "New report";
   $data['msg']="";

   if(isset($_POST['saveit'])) {
     $this->Marksheet->tm();  
     //$data['marks_obt'] = $this->Marksheet->$mark;
     $data['msg']="report added";
   }

   $this->load->view('header',$data);
   $this->load->view('welcome_create', $data);
}
```

**view/welcome_create.php file**

I want to be my total marks in text box.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>MO</td>
    <td><input type="text"  value="<?php if    (isset($mark)) echo $mark ?>"/>    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="submit" name="saveit" id="saveit" value="Save"/></td>
    <td><input type="button" name="cancel" id="cancel" value="Cancel"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you need to use `$this->input->post('math');` instead of `$_POST['math']`
2. var_dump() incoming values if they are string you need to convert them to integer . you can not add these values like: "4" (string) + 5 (integer)
3. if incoming data is string you need to convert them to integer.

   `$math = "23";
   $math = intval($math);`

Comment: no need to convert it into int. PHP auto convert it.